# Query on kubernetes metrics-server metrics values

Tags: kubernetes, metrics, docker-api

I am using metrics-server(https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server/) to collect the core metrics from containers in a kubernetes cluster.

I could fetch 2 resource usage metrics per container.

- cpu usage
- memory usage

However its not clear to me whether

- these metrics are accumulated over time or they are already sampled for a particular time window(1 minute/ 30 seconds..)
- What are the units for the above metric values. For CPU usage, is it the number of cores or milliseconds? And for memory usage i assume its the bytes usage.
- While computing CPU usage metric value, does metrics-server already take care of dividing the container usage by the host system usage?

Also, if i have to compare these metrics with the docker-api metrics, how to compute CPU usage % for a given container?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Metrics are scraped periodically from kubelets. The default resolution duration is 60s, which can be overriden with the `--metric-resolution=<duration>` flag.
2. The value and unit (cpu - cores in decimal SI, memory - bytes in binary SI) are arrived at by using the `Quantity` serializer in the k8s [apimachinery](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery) package. You can read about it from the comments in the [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/master/pkg/api/resource/quantity.go)
3. No, the CPU metric is not relative to the host system usage as you can see that it's not a percentage value. It represents the rate of change of the total amount of CPU seconds consumed by the container by core. If this value increases by 1 within one second, the pod consumes 1 CPU core (or 1000 milli-cores) in that second.
   To arrive at a relative value, depending on your use case, you can divide the CPU metric for a pod by that for the node, since metrics-server exposes both `/pods` and `/nodes` endpoints.